# How to add a custom page section in Zen Cart that can be turned on and off in EZ Pages

Tags: zen-cart

I am not so familiar with Zen Cart, I want to add a relatively small contact form box that can be added to/taken from pages via the red and green buttons in the Tools -> EZ-Pages section of the admin panel.

Thanks

Comment: Why not use the contact form that is already available in zen cart?

Answer (score 0):

If it's simple HTML that you want to put in your custom page, then you can just create a new page an put your HTML into it.

If it's conditional PHP code that you want to run, that's not supported in EZ-Pages.

But, to Robert's point, how is your "custom page" different from the built-in Contact Us page?